# Cloudflare + Amazon Web Server (wordpress) + Bitnami

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, bitnami

I'm having trouble converting my website from http//: to Https://. I'm currently running Amazon Web Server with route 53 with Bitnami on my wordpress site. I changed the DNS records on my domain site and Amazon route 53 to the appropriate cloudfare dns. I noticed that my website layout changed during the https:// and my layout completely normal in Http:

[Layout shifted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDdfE.png)

[Should I add something into my DNS?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9C6B.png)

Sorry ahead of time, I'm new to this and still a novice

Comment: Nothing to do with DNS. Likely issue is your site is attempting to serve CSS/JS off HTTP instead of HTTPS. Most browsers will block that as insecure. Check your browser console for details.

Comment: https://www.icontrolwp.com/blog/enabling-cloudflares-universal-flexible-ssl-wordpress-without-infinite-redirect-loops/

Comment: I inspected my style sheet and undercover this http://imgur.com/a/4KYLE. I even went into my https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/115005733547/Screen_Shot_2017-02-09_at_16.09.31.png and changed my settings

Comment: CloudFlare typically takes over DNS, so Route53 wouldn't be used, unless you have one of the less used setups. Problem is likely to be insecure images or resources not being loaded.

Comment: I see thanks! I believe I found the issue and it was my CSS/JS off HTTP thanks!

Comment: Please answer your own question, so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Into wordpress theme editor, under styles.css modified google front link.

[Added "S'after the http:// to secure the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsZya.png)